# HTML keyboard tag as symbol in editor

Tags: feature-request

I've seen the keyboard tag of HTML the first time here at SR. The main HTML functions are available in the toolbar of the editor. Why is there no symbol for add the keyboard tag ? For SR this symbol could improve and make the writting of answers and questions more comfortable.

Comment: None of the sites have it, though I seem to recall there's a FF extention for it

Comment: I use Google Chrome. Actually I do not think it makes sense to install for such things an extension. On the one hand Stackexchange do not support all tags and on the other hand the implementation of symbol would improve the quality of the editor.

Comment: Note that [`kbd` may be used for any kind of user input](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215133/193139), not just keyboard keys.

Comment: Though, I sometimes need to think whether it was `<keyb>` or `<kbd>`. Cannot hurt to have it in the toolbar, as it proves quite useful now and then (@IrgendwPointer I saw it a lot on other SE sites. On Android.SE we often use it to indicate *hardware* keys like <kbd>power</kbd>).